# Triangle inequality of a nasty metric $\rho(A,B)=\max\left\{\sup_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}|x-y|,\sup_{y\in B}\inf_{x\in A}|x-y|\right\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This was a qual problem in Winter 2012 at my university. I feel comfortable verifying everything but the triangle inequality.

> Let $\Omega$ denote the set of all nonempty closed subsets of $[0,1]$ and let $\rho\colon\Omega\times\Omega\to[0,1]$ be defined by
>   $$
> \rho(A,B)=\max\left\{\sup_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}|x-y|,\sup_{y\in B}\inf_{x\in A}|x-y|\right\}$$
>   Show that $(\Omega,\rho)$ is a metric space.

Intuitively, I think of $\sup_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}|x-y|$ as the closest distance from each $x\in A$ to the set $B$, and then taking the largest of those.

Is there a clever way to see $\rho$ respects the triangle inequality?

Comment: What topological space are you refering to when you claim that $\Omega$ _is a closed subset of a compact space_?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Sorry, I wasn't thinking. I meant to say the closed sets in $\Omega$ are compact in $[0,1]$.

Comment: If we're picky, it's not a metric space since $\rho(A,\varnothing) = \infty$. Make it "nonempty closed sets" or make a special provision for the empty set.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, I'll change that.

Comment: In textbooks this is called the "Hausdorff metric", in case you wanted to look-up a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://planetmath.org/HausdorffMetric) at planetmath.org has a very brief sketch of the proof of the triangle inequality; you might like to read it and see whether you can fill in the details. [This PDF](http://www-math.mit.edu/phase2/UJM/vol1/HAUSF.PDF) has a complete proof in case you get stuck.

Comment: @YNChew: You’re welcome.